# if (i > .length) not working inside for loop (image slider)

Tags: javascript

First thanks to all the people on this platform! I really appreciate all the help you can get to learn new stuff on the internet. My project is almost completed, I got one last thing that doesn't work properly. I have a for loop which contains code for an image slider. Every image has it's own arrows (right and left) which change by changing the current image. Here's the code inside the for loop:

```
for (let i = 0 ; i < insMax.length; i++) {
          if (i < 1) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('arrowleft')[i].removeEventListener('click' , insLeft);
          } else {
            document.getElementsByClassName('arrowleft')[i].addEventListener('click' , insLeft);
            function insLeft() {
              document.getElementById('Popup'+i).classList.add("hide");
              document.getElementById('Popup'+(i - 1)).classList.remove("hide");
            }
          }
          if (i > insMax.length) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('arrowright')[i].removeEventListener('click' , insRight);
          } else {
            document.getElementsByClassName('arrowright')[i].addEventListener('click' , insRight);
            function insRight() {
              document.getElementById('Popup'+i).classList.add("hide");
              document.getElementById('Popup'+(i + 1)).classList.remove("hide");
            }
          }
        }
```

The weird thing again is, that the first if statement works as it should. When the first image is active, you can't click anymore on the left arrow. But the right arrow never works since `'Popup'+(i + 1)` gets marked as null, which means that the if statement doesn't work. I also tried using `if (i > insMax.length - 1)` or `if (i == insMax.length)` but nothing works.

Comment: Since you are looping from `0` to `insMax.length - 1` effectively (because only as long as `i` is `<` (less than) `insMax.length`, the loop body gets executed), the condition `if (i > insMax.length)` can never be true because it would require 2 iterations _beyond_ your loop end condition. Let's say `insMax.length` is 5. Then, the loop will run for values of `i` from 0 to 4 and stop as soon as `i` would become 5, because 5 is not less than 5. But your condition would then say `if (i > 5)` so it would only be true with `i` being 6, which it can never be because the last iteration is with `i`=4!

Comment: Also, you are creating _new_ functions called `insLeft` and `insRight` every time, so the `removeEventListener` can never work either, because the function added as listener will be a previous "version" of it and will never equal the one you pass into the removal function.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is defined as:

`for (let i = 0 ; i < insMax.length; i++)`

Because the condition of the loop is `i < insMax.length` the value of `i` will NEVER be greater than or equal to `insMax.length`. As soon as `i` equals `insMax.length` the loop will exit before doing anything inside the loop.

I would suggest you devise something outside this loop to do your check or leverage a `while ...` or `do ... while` pattern.